# In case of an error occurred only on one node of grid, how assure data replication by infinispan in all other nodes?

Tags: asynchronous, transactions, infinispan

I'm currently using infinispan with following configuration:

1. transactional mode (optimistic locking - repeatable read)
2. only one node of grid assigned to perform put/remove operations (hereafter called master node), and all remaining grid nodes able to perform only read operations (hereafter called read nodes). I have a low total number of grid nodes.
3. synchronous replycated mode

Now, I would like to know how I have to change my infinispan configuration in order to work with all following characteristics at the same time:

1. maintain transactional mode (optimistic locking - repeatable read)
2. maintain only one master node and all other as read nodes
3. asynchronous replycated mode
4. in case of an error of data replication occurred only in one read node X (e.g. ISPN000220: Problems un-marshalling remote command from byte buffer: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Attempt to read a backreference with an invalid ID), it is ensured that data are properly replicated in all other nodes, and then it will be infinispan to retry data replication on read node X (once it has been re-deployed with fixed error)
5. finally, I need to intercept in the master node all Exceptions related to possibly errors occurred during execution of asynchronous transactions, in order to store error messages in a dedicated db table. How can I intercept these Exceptions?

Many thanks

Francesco Sclano

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a need for you to separate between writer and reader nodes, because Infinispan acquires locks in a single node already, avoiding deadlocks.

If you want to track failures, it's probably better to swith the async cache API and add listeners to the notifying future to find out when the operation has completed, or when an error has ocurred. This way, the caller of the cache does not have to wait immediately for a response.

Also, if the reason of switching to async is performance, maybe you can switch to distribution, which scales better as you add more nodes to the cluster, since it replicates data to only a subset of the cluster. Enabling L1 caching with distribution makes sure that reads are still performant.

Comment: In case of an error of data replication occurred only in one read node X (e.g. ISPN000220: Problems un-marshalling remote command from byte buffer: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Attempt to read a backreference with an invalid ID), it is ensured that data are properly replicated in all other nodes, and then it will be infinispan to retry data replication on read node X (once it has been re-deployed with fixed error)

Comment: Topology of grid designed for my project expects only one node that is able to write.
Unfortunately I must use a replicated, transactional, synchronous cache.

So, is it not possible to obtain 4. point above with a replicated transaction synchronous cache?

Comment: You can achieve that, but the retry must be done by your code.